Need help setting rms values with code. trying to animate talking with pictures
import cv2
import numpy as np
import wave
import os
import shutil

# Constants
AUDIO_FILE = "/home/kit/sfml_project/sound_test/Start-1.wav"
IMAGE_PATH_CLOSED_1 = "images/Start4.png"  # Mouth closed image set 1
IMAGE_PATH_OPEN_1 = "images/Start5.png"    # Mouth open image set 1
IMAGE_PATH_CLOSED_2 = "images/Start6.png"  # Mouth closed image set 2
IMAGE_PATH_OPEN_2 = "images/Start7.png"    # Mouth open image set 2
FRAME_DIR = "frames/"
FRAME_RATE = 60  # 60 frames per second
MAX_SAME_FRAMES = 500  # Maximum number of consecutive identical frames

# Ensure frame directory exists
os.makedirs(FRAME_DIR, exist_ok=True)

# Load images
imageClosed1 = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH_CLOSED_1)
imageOpen1 = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH_OPEN_1)
imageClosed2 = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH_CLOSED_2)
imageOpen2 = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH_OPEN_2)

if imageClosed1 is None or imageOpen1 is None or imageClosed2 is None or imageOpen2 is None:
    print("Error loading images.")
    exit(-1)

# Open the audio file
wf = wave.open(AUDIO_FILE, 'rb')

# Verify audio properties
print(f"Channels: {wf.getnchannels()}")
print(f"Sample Width: {wf.getsampwidth()}")
print(f"Frame Rate: {wf.getframerate()}")
print(f"Number of Frames: {wf.getnframes()}")

# Calculate the total duration of the audio file in seconds and the number of frames
audio_duration = wf.getnframes() / wf.getframerate()
total_frames_needed = int(audio_duration * FRAME_RATE)
print(f"Audio Duration: {audio_duration}s, Total Frames Needed: {total_frames_needed}")

# Read the entire audio file to determine sound presence
data = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
samples = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)

# Verify samples were read correctly
print(f"Total Samples Read: {len(samples)}")

# Calculate frame size
frame_size = int(wf.getframerate() / FRAME_RATE)
print(f"Frame Size: {frame_size}")

# Calculate RMS values for each frame
rms_values = []
for i in range(total_frames_needed):
    start = i * frame_size
    end = start + frame_size
    frame_samples = samples[start:end]
    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(frame_samples))) if len(frame_samples) > 0 else 0
    rms_values.append(rms)

# Debug: Print the first few RMS values to check they are being calculated correctly
print("First 10 RMS values:", rms_values[:10])
print("Min RMS value:", np.min(rms_values))
print("Max RMS value:", np.max(rms_values))
print("Mean RMS value:", np.mean(rms_values))

# Determine the lowest RMS value as the silence threshold
silence_threshold = np.min(rms_values) * 1.1  # Adjust factor slightly above the minimum
print(f"Silence Threshold: {silence_threshold}")

# Identify voice segments based on RMS values
voice_segments = []
current_voice = 0  # 0 for no sound, 1 for first voice, 2 for second voice
for rms in rms_values:
    if rms < silence_threshold:
        current_voice = 0
    elif current_voice == 0:
        current_voice = 1 if len(voice_segments) % 2 == 0 else 2
    voice_segments.append(current_voice)

# Debug: Print voice segments for the first few frames
print("First 10 voice segments: ", voice_segments[:10])

wf.close()

# Create the animation
frameCounter = 0
same_frame_count = 0
last_frame = None

cv2.namedWindow("Talking Animation")

while frameCounter < total_frames_needed:
    # Decide which set of images to use based on the current voice
    if voice_segments[frameCounter] == 1:
        imageClosed = imageClosed1
        imageOpen = imageOpen1
    elif voice_segments[frameCounter] == 2:
        imageClosed = imageClosed2
        imageOpen = imageOpen2
    else:
        imageClosed = imageClosed1
        imageOpen = imageOpen1

    if voice_segments[frameCounter] in [1, 2]:
        currentFrame = imageOpen
    else:
        currentFrame = imageClosed

    # Check for consecutive identical frames
    if last_frame is not None and np.array_equal(last_frame, currentFrame):
        same_frame_count += 1
        if same_frame_count > MAX_SAME_FRAMES:
            print(f"Too many identical frames ({same_frame_count}). Terminating program.")
            break
    else:
        same_frame_count = 0

    last_frame = currentFrame.copy()

    # Display the current frame
    if currentFrame is not None:
        cv2.imshow("Talking Animation", currentFrame)
        frame_path = os.path.join(FRAME_DIR, f"frame_{frameCounter:06d}.png")
        cv2.imwrite(frame_path, currentFrame)
        print(f"Saved frame {frameCounter}")
        frameCounter += 1

    # Check for 'q' key press
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Combine frames and audio into a video if the program wasn't terminated early
if same_frame_count <= MAX_SAME_FRAMES:
    os.system(f"ffmpeg -framerate {FRAME_RATE} -i {FRAME_DIR}frame_%06d.png -i {AUDIO_FILE} -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict experimental talking_animation_with_audio.mp4")

# Delete all frames
shutil.rmtree(FRAME_DIR)


Any ideas on what is wrong, when I run code it just repeats the same frame instead of sound 1 character 1 speaks, sound 2 character 2 speaks.
I tried averaging a minimum rms to set as silent. I set silent to minimum rms. I'm expecting code to read wav and measure rms and set characters but it's just silent. I input a kill code at 500 frames because it would print the same frame until done.
